# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, invoke

I need help. I am working with an arraylist, and suddenly I get this error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

This is the code where it shows the exception...

```
foreach (PC_list x in onlinelist) {
  if ((nowtime.Subtract(x.time)).TotalSeconds > 5) {
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
      index = Main_ListBox.FindString(x.PcName);
      if(index != ListBox.NoMatches)
      Main_ListBox.Items.RemoveAt(index);
    }));
    onlinelist.Remove(x);
    //Thread.Sleep(500);
  }
}
```

Where

```
public class PC_list {
    public string PcName;
    public string ip;
    public string status;
    public string NickName;
    public DateTime time;

}
```

*Notes:*

- onlinelist is an arraylist
- nowtime and x.time are DateTime.

**Call Stack**

```
mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.ArrayList.ArrayListEnumeratorSimple.MoveNext() + 0x122 bytes    
BlueBall.exe!BlueBall.BlueBall.clean_arraylist() Line 74 + 0x1a8 bytes  C#
BlueBall.exe!BlueBall.BlueBall.server() Line 61 + 0x8 bytes C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state) + 0x63 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool ignoreSyncCtx) + 0xb0 bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x2c bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x44 bytes   
[Native to Managed Transition]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
foreach (PC_list x in onlinelist)
{            
     onlinelist.Remove(x); // cannot do this
}
```

This is the heart of the problem. You cannot remove an item from a collection as you are iterating over it in a `foreach`. Your options are to make a local *copy* of the list prior to the loop, loop over the copy, and remove from the original. Or you can keep a separate list of items to remove *after* you finish the original loop. Or you can switch to a `for` loop and iterate over it backwards, which allows you to remove items from the *end* as you go.

While you're here, if you are not stuck working with C# 1 / .NET 1.1 / Visual Studio 2003, you might want to consider switching from `ArrayList` to the stronger `List<T>`, where `T` is the type of the object in the collection. In your case, that would be a `List<PC_list>`. You can find it at `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`.

And since your question is tagged `multithreading`, it would also be a smart idea to consult the [collections built with concurrency in mind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot modify onlinelist in a foreach block. This is why you get this error.
Try this:

```
ArrayList RemoveList = new ArrayList();
foreach (PC_list x in onlinelist)
            {
                if ((nowtime.Subtract(x.time)).TotalSeconds > 5)
                {
                    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                    {
                        index = Main_ListBox.FindString(x.PcName);
                        if(index != ListBox.NoMatches)
                            Main_ListBox.Items.RemoveAt(index);
                    }));

                    RemoveList.Add(x);
                    //Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            }
foreach (PC_list x in RemoveList)
        {
                onlinelist.Remove(x);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, your logic is broken. You're asking the iterator to move to the next object after `x` in the list, but you've removed `x` from the list, so there is no such thing. There are a lot of workarounds, but the traditional way to do it is to remove the *previous* object at the top of the loop. (This only works for collections that do not reorganize on removals.)

Comment: That's not quite it.  You can't remove ANY item from the list while you're in the foreach loop.