# Multithreaded access to non-threadsafe values within a System.Collection.Concurrent?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, linq, concurrentdictionary

If I am using a collection from the `System.Collection.Concurrent` namespace, such as `ConcurrentDictionary<K, V>`, with a key and/or value type that is not threadsafe, for instance `ConcurrentDictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>` **What are the possible issues faced?**

I assume that I can do any operation that I please on the `ConcurrentDictionary` itself, but what if I create a `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` of the `Dictionary<int, int>` from that `ConcurrentDictionary` and modify it?

Here I create the list with LINQ in "one line" though I assume that once the `ToList` is executed I am out of the safety of the `ConcurrentDictionary` `lock`?

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>> conDict = ...;
conDict.Select(x => x.Value).ToList().ForEach(x => x.Add(1, 2));
```

If that is safe or unsafe I then assume this is too

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>> conDict = ...;
var regDictList = conDict.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
regDictList.ForEach(x => x.Add(1, 2));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) is by itself self for access from multiple threads ([`TryAdd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267291(v=vs.110).aspx), [`TryGetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267270(v=vs.110).aspx), Etc...).

It's important to understand that it's not the objects contained by the `ConcurrentDictionary` that are thread-safe but the `ConcurrentDictionary` itself.

---

If you access a specific value contained by the dictionary from multiple threads than you have to make sure it is thread-safe as well.

Since the result from:

```
conDict.Select(x => x.Value)
```

is:

```
IEnumerable<Dictionary<int, int>>
```

and it no longer has anything to do with the `ConcurrentDictionary` - a `List<Dictionary<int, int>>` retrieved by:

```
conDict.Select(x => x.Value).ToList()
```

is of course ***NOT thread-safe***

Comment: So in my example above if I would like to keep the `conDict.Values` thread safe I would need to change the type to `ConcurrentDictionary<int, ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>>`?

Comment: @KDecker Yes, but note that you shouldn't modify the outer `ConcurrentDictionary` from another thread while iterating over its values ([Like any collection is not allowed to be modified while being iterated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761959/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute-c-sharp)).

Comment: Every time you modify ***a specific object*** from multiple threads, make sure that ***that specific object*** is thread-safe.

Comment: @TamirVered your warning about modifying the collection does not apply to the classes in the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace, all of the collections in that namespace take a "snapshot" of the collection and iterate over that snapshot. Basically any time you do a `foreach(var foo in myConcurrentDictionary)` internally it is doing something similar to you doing `foreach(var foo in myConcurrentDictionary.ToList())`

Comment: @Scott Linq is lazy, it iterates over the original collection until `.ToList` or something like that (which iterates the `IEnumerable`) is called

Comment: That's why I said "*something similar to you doing*", internally it is much more complicated, I was just trying to point out that you will never get the error you linked to in your comment from a `System.Collections.Concurrent` collection

Comment: Actually, I was kinda wrong, it does not do a snapshot, however it is still safe to modify the outer dictionary while enumerating, [the MSDN specifically states that it is safe to do so.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287131(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1)

Comment: Here is a webpage I was just reading that I think might be related to this sub-discussion Tamir and Scott (https://arbel.net/2013/02/03/best-practices-for-using-concurrentdictionary/). It discusses the "snapshot mechanic".